# Create tuple from webscraped data without splitting data into characters

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to webscrape a series of venue names into a tuple. My code sort of works but splits the venue names into individual characters rather than keep them whole.

Desired output:
`(Prior,)(Rat the Cafe,)(Ampersand Coffee and Food,)(Umberto Espresso Bar,)(Brother Alec,)(Short Round,)(Jerry Joy,)(The Old Milk Bar,)(Little Henri,)(Northern Soul,)`

Current output: `[('P', 'r', 'i', 'o', 'r'), ('R', 'a', 't', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'C', 'a', 'f', 'e'),` etc.

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury' #go to the website
response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
type(soup_cafe_names)

cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", }) #scrape the elements
cafeNamesClean = [cafe.text.strip() for cafe in cafeNames] #clean the elements
cafeTuple = [tuple(cafe) for cafe in cafeNamesClean] #send to tuple

print(cafeTuple)
```

Comment: change to, ```cafeTuple = [(cafe,) for cafe in cafeNamesClean]```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much. Can I ask why my method was doing the wrong thing?

Comment: from doc's,  If iterable is specified the tuple is initialized from iterable's items so you are seeing above result when using ``tuple()``